# Why isn't the hyperlink clickable?

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, format, textview

I'm writing an app that among other things displays HTML-formatted code in a TextView.
The problem I'm having is that although it does format the HTML to look as it should the hyperlinks included in the text are not clickable.

Anyone got any idea why?

This is what I've used:

```java
contentText.setText("\n" + Html.fromHtml(HomeScreen.offer_description[offerSelected]));
contentText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And in the .xml files:

```xml
<TextView android:id="@+id/contentText" 
          android:autoLink="all" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="TextView" 
          android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

Any help would be great...thanks a lot!

Comment: Real quick: have you seen this demo? http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.html

Comment: I have, yes...and I think there's something I'm missing since I've included about everything I'm able to tell from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which android api you are working on?
This code should do fine. (working for me atleast).

If not, try 
android:linksClickable="true" in the textView declaration

Comment: I'm using Android 2.3's API...whichever that is.

Comment: And amazingly it still doesn't work...I really have no idea what I could've missed...